# How do I merge columns modifying the data on a Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

community!

I have this Dataframe:

[Dataframe I want to modify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6aD5.jpg)

And I want to merge the columns and organize the data so it looks like this:

[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQwzJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've done already?

Answer (score 0):

This sample code should help.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "pais":[1970, 1971],
        "Brazil":[8, 11],
        "China": [34, 12]
    }
)
df = df.set_index('pais')

print("Input\n", df)

d = {
    "ano": [],
    "pais": [],
    "x": [],
}
width, height = df.shape
for h in range(height):
    for w in range(width):
        d["ano"].append(df.index[h])
        d["pais"].append(df.columns[w])
        d["x"].append(df.iloc[[h],[w]].to_numpy()[0][0])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)

print("Output\n", df2)
```

---

#### Input

```
       Brazil  China
pais               
1970       8     34
1971      11     12
```

#### Output

```
    ano    pais   x
0  1970  Brazil   8
1  1970   China  34
2  1971  Brazil  11
3  1971   China  12
```

Comment: Thank you, Jitesh.
Despite your reply was very clear, someone helped me with an easier solution, using the function melt:

new_df = df.melt(id_vars = ['pais'], var_name = 'ano', value_name = ' x')